# Different between Spring MVC vs Oracle ADF?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oracle-adf

Different between Spring MVC vs Oracle ADF
Advantage and disadvantage of Spring MVC and Oracle ADF
Which one is best Spring MVC or Oracle ADF?

Comment: You can find it from Google. this is not right place for this question.

Answer (score 3):

I read it somewhere that,

> Oracle ADF is not widely spread across enterprise java development:
>   projects with this technology are often about migration of old Oracle
>   Forms application. It is not open source like spring is and you'll
>   need weblogic servers to run your apps. However, it is possible to use
>   spring within adf apps.

Refer this [Link](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Spring-3X-Vs-Oracle-ADF-46964.S.66035984)

Comment: You can run Oracle ADF application on other servers, like Tomcat.

Comment: @Fortega You only can run Oracle ADF application on either Weblogic or GlassFish If i am not mistaken

Comment: @taymedee Oracle ADF only runs on Weblogic. Oracle ADF Essentials (which is a free subset of ADF which does not include weblogic-specific functionality) runs on GlassFish and on Tomcat.